# How can I redirect requests to a configured Shiro loginUrl if the user is already authenticated?

Tags: java, authentication, shiro

I have a webapp using Shiro for authentication. The relevant parts of the web.xml and shiro.ini are:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
    <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

and

```
[main]
authc.loginUrl = /authoring/login.html
authc.successUrl  = /authoring
logout.redirectUrl = /authoring/login.html

[users]
foo = foo

[urls]
/authoring/logout = logout
/authoring/** = authc
```

Shiro correctly intercepts all requests from non-authenticated clients and redirects to the configured loginUrl (and then forwards them on to the requested page after successful authentication). What I'd like to have happen is, if an authenticated client makes an explicit request to /authoring/login.html, redirect that to /authoring. This would ONLY happen if the client is authenticated.

For example, think of how Gmail works - trying to access mail.google.com (or even https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin) when you've already logged in redirects you to the inbox. Is this possible with Shiro out of the box? If not, what's the right way to implement it?

Answer (score 2):

You could handle the login request yourself or using your framework, you would need to change your `shiro.ini` to use a [PassThruAuthenticationFilter](http://shiro.apache.org/static/1.2.1/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/web/filter/authc/PassThruAuthenticationFilter.html)

```
authc = org.apache.shiro.web.filter.authc.PassThruAuthenticationFilter
```

You could now check if the user is logged in and redirect if true:

```
Subject currentUser = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
if(currentUser.isAuthenticated()){
    //redirect
}else{
    AuthenticationToken token =  new UsernamePasswordToken(username, password);
    currentUser.login(token);
    WebUtils.redirectToSavedRequest(request, response, "index.xhtml");
}
```

This isn't an totally out of the box solution. I am not certain if you can get the success url outside of the authentication, you could manually redirect `WebUtils.issueRedirect(req, resp, url)`

Comment: Are you suggesting extending the PassThruAuthenticationFilter and then putting that code in an overridden method? If so which method - I can't seem to find the appropriate one. Or are you saying that code should be in a controller? We don't currently have a login controller, and I'm trying to figure out how to use your recommendation.

Comment: No i'm suggesting you put that code in whatever serves your login page. I use jsf so that code goes inside my login method in my Backing bean

Comment: You could extend the default filter `org.apache.shiro.web.filter.authc.FormAuthenticationFilter` to do what you want, you would probably have access to the success url from here as well

Comment: 6 years later, thank you for pointing me towards `WebUtils.redirectToSavedRequest`, it's exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue and worked around it by turning the login page into a JSP and adding a redirection at the beginning:

```
<%
    if (SecurityUtils.getSubject().isAuthenticated()) {
        response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath());
    }
%>
```